# SchedulerLike is not an exported member

Tags: ionic-framework, rxjs, angularfire2

So I was going to work on an Ionic app that I was working on last year and I didn't change anything in framework or anything. So I launch the command "ionic serve" and my app crashes saying a lot of imports don't work like in the picture:

[image]

- I've tried installing rxjs-compat (even though I haven't updated rxjs) and still doesn't work.
- I just did "npm i" just in case something was missing and then launched my app.

Does anyone know what could be the reason that is making everything crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you got unexpected updates.

Please check root directory of your project, if `npm i` didn't work it means you don't have `package-lock.json`. If you have it - try to delete `node_modules` and execute `npm install` again.

Also check whether `yarn.lock` is there, then you need to use `yarn` to install proper packages.

Without `yarn.lock` and `package-lock.json` you can only guess suitable versions.
If you remember a date when it worked - try to check which versions were actual then on http://npmjs.com/ and specify them explicitly in the `packages.json` without `^` or `~` prefix.

Comment: It worked! Now I have to fix some other different things but that solution fixed it, thank you!